# Inserir array no banco de dados usando PHP e SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array, sql-insert

Eu estou tentando inserir valores vindos de um *array* dentro do banco de dados usando PHP, mas estou tento dificuldade no método aplicado. É a primeira vez que uso *arrays* para isso.

Meu código atual é:

```
<input type='text' id="productName[]" name="productName[]">

<input type='text' id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]">

include_once("connection.php");

 $name = $_POST['productName'];
 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$name = '"' . implode('","', $name) . '"';
$quantity = '"' . implode('","', $quantity) . '"';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name IN ($name)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $sql);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn_app) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $itemId = $row['product_id'];
    };

$insert = "INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ('$quantity','$itemId')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $insert);
```

Eu preciso que seja inserido no banco de dados cada produto e sua respectiva quantidade.
Por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO item_box (quantity, product_id)VALUES (13,2),(23,3),(40,3);
```

Atualmente o código aponta erro na syntax do *SQL*, pois está sendo retornado assim:

```
INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ("20","30","40","50","2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi, você faz uma consulta na tabela product para recuperar o id, para depois adicionar o item na tabela de item_box .

Como os seus inputs são arrays, uma forma de adicionar na tabela item_box seria a seguinte:

```
$contador = count($_POST["productName"]);
for ($x = 0; $x < $contador; $x++){
$produto = $_POST["productName"][$x];
$quantidade = $_POST["quantity"][$x];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = '$produto'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $sql);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn_app) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$itemId = $row['product_id'];
$insert = "INSERT INTO item_box (quantity,product_id) VALUES ('$quantidade','$itemId')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_app, $insert);
};
}
}
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado, funcionou certinho mas está inserindo duplicado, sabe como resolver?

Comment: No caso está sendo inserido os mesmos dados na mesma quantidade de arrays

Comment: Eu fiz alterações na resposta, isso deve evitar o problema que você relatou